# Parameter not passing to SQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I need a sanity check here.... I have a very simple ExecuteNonQuery. I am passing values to a sproc but it keeps returning an error that the first value wasn't even passed.

```
 using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCommandLogError = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.AddWithValue("logEntry", logEntry);
                        sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.AddWithValue("EventLogEntryType", EventLogEntryType);
                        sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.AddWithValue("EventID", eventId);
                        sqlCommandLogError.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
```

I verified that parameter exists in the procedure
I nulled them out in the procedure to make sure that in fact the fields in the sproc were correct and it worked (it put all nulls in the database)

Any idea why the procedure thinks no parameters are getting passed?

**UPDATED Question** Eventhough this is answered I would love to hear from some of the experts out their: Is the @symbol in a parameter required (it seems not) and why would it even find my sproc without putting in a command type.

Comment: You need to set the CommandType property of the SqlCommand to StoredProcedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Also add `@` to key names.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   sqlConnection.Open();
   using (SqlCommand sqlCommandLogError = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc",
          sqlConnection))
   {
      sqlCommandLogError.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logEntry", logEntry);
      sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventLogEntryType",
                                              EventLogEntryType);
      sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", eventId);

      sqlCommandLogError.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: actually I kept the @ out of it. It is not required. I forgot to se the Command Type :(. Whats odd is that the message was telling me I was missing a parameter but in fact I was missing the commandType. I would have expected it not to even find the sproc had I not had a correct commandType.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to come up with the accurate answer because the source code for the SQL Server stored procedure "MyStoredProc" is not attached. Based on the information available, your stored procedure parameter names should be preceded with "@" character.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameter name with @ and SqlType and  like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommandLogError = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@logEntry", SqlDbType.YourParamType) {Value = logEntry});
                    sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventLogEntryType", SqlDbType.YourParamType) {Value = EventLogEntryType});
                    sqlCommandLogError.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventID", SqlDbType.YourParamType) {Value = eventId});

                    sqlCommandLogError.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I won't down vote it but you are missing what is really wrong. The reason for my error was I was missing the CommandType declaration.